# WCF client. Client Certificate. First call success, Second call fails

Tags: c#, wcf, network-programming, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to connect to a soap web service over https, with soap11 and client certificate credentials using c# .NET 4.5. I use the tool of vs to add service reference and it create a soap client for me.

I have create a customBinding to accomplish https over soap11:

App.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="*****" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"/>
          <httpsTransport useDefaultWebProxy="false" requireClientCertificate="true" allowCookies="false" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="******************"
            behaviorConfiguration="******************"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="******************"
            contract="******************"
            name="******************" />
    </client>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="******************">
        <clientCredentials>
          <clientCertificate findValue="******************" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        </clientCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

c# code:

```
     var client = new IConsultService.ConsultServiceClient();
     client.consult("1"); 
     client.consult("1"); <!-- fail error 404 - there was not endpoint listening at
```

**If I post without certificate in receive a tomcat 404, if I send the client certificate works ok the first time and it seems to me that I'm being redirected. The problem is that at the sencond request fail (404), also if I instantiate the client again fails. Only work again when stop the application and start it again. It seems that somethings is cached in the static stack of the program.**

And since is a 404 my guess is that is something from the client certificate, if I request without the certificate the error is the same.

I tryied to create bindings programatically, set ClientBase.CacheSetting = CacheSetting.AlwaysOff without luck.

Edit1: 
Using System.Net.HttpWebRequest happens the same, first request ok, second request 404.

Edit2: 
It seems that there is something on the handshake first request send "Certificate, Client Key Exchange" and second request "Change cipher Key Exchange"

is there a way to force to close the channel and always send"certificate, client key exchange"?

[image][image]

Thanks

Comment: Interesting I have the opposite problem. First call fails, all subsequent calls succeed.

Answer (score 0):

First, if we authenticate the client with X509certificate, we commonly need to establish the trust relationship between the server and the client, namely, we should install each other’s certificate in the trusted root certificate authority, and the client needs to provide an Identity to confirm the identity of the server (this is usually the public key of the server's certificate, or the host name)

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://10.157.13.69:4386/" binding="netTcpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ITestService" contract="ServiceReference1.ITestService"
    name="NetTcpBinding_ITestService">
    <identity>
        <dns value="vabqia969VM" />
    </identity>
</endpoint>
```

Second, I suspect the issue is caused by the TLS version. Have you tried to upgrade the Dotnetframework of these project? at least 4.6.2 above. Please refer to the following document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Hi @abraham the connection works in the first request but not in the second. It seems that the channel simplify the handshake and therefore do not send the "client key exchange" in the second request, seems that there is some kind of session going on. The problem is that I need to send the client key exchange every time like it's the first connection. But under the hood .NET don't allow me to do it. Only finishing the process and starting it again works. About TLS version I used TLS11 and TLS12 same problem.

Comment: Do you have tried to add the Security element to the custom binding on the server side? it could specify the negotiation process for authenticating the client.
<security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" />

Comment: Hi @Abraham the problem was that the server do not resume correctly the TLS session and I didn't found on .NET ( on the client side ) a parameter to indicate to make a full handshare in every request. I resolve it other language that have that parameter, but would be great if .NET have it.